# Android How to manage differennt applications in single app

Tags: android

I like to create a application to provide menu for some other applications. Once user click on the menu item, the perticular application will launch. Apart from this I want to give option to add/remove application from the menu.

How I can manage list of applications into single APK file?

regards,
Android IT

Comment: Are you talking about applications installed on the users phone? Or applications that you want to package into your APK?

Comment: Application I want to package in APK.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Intents to launch Activities in other apps from your app. You can have a broadcast receiver listening for these Intents